# setBackgroundColor in ListView item is coloring multiple items

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in Android Studio with over 20 items (which means that there is a scrollbar to navigate through it). However, when the user clicks on an item, my code is supposed to color the selected item, which it does, but it also selects another item farther ahead in the list.

My list is basically a list of a few classes available in a certain university.

Here's my `ListView` XML code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/class_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is my `onCreate` full code:

```
class_search = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.class_search);
final ArrayList<String> PurdueClasses = new ArrayList<>();
PurdueClasses.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PurdueClasses)));

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        ClassSearch.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        PurdueClasses
);

class_search.setAdapter(adapter);

class_search.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        if (!SelectedClassesNames.contains(name)){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SelectedClassesNames.add(name);
            //I have tried both ways below and they both have the same problem I described
            //view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            class_search.getChildAt(position - class_search.getFirstVisiblePosition()).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item De-Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SelectedClassesNames.remove(name);
            //I have tried both ways below and they both have the same problem I described
            //view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            class_search.getChildAt(position - class_search.getFirstVisiblePosition()).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        }
    }
);
```

Here is an example of when I click on **CS 18000 - Problem Solving And Object-Oriented Programming**:
[image: CS180 Selected]

But then, when I scroll down I also see another item colored:
[image: Random item colored]

Comment: listviews recycle the views to save on memory. now that you know the issue, you can now look up a resolution. :)

Comment: one more tip: use `RecyclerView` with the `ViewHolder` pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the recycling mechanism of the `listView`.

The `Listview` is recycling the same view for rendering your items! You can use a custom adapter and store your selected view position inside some variable; then in the `onCreateView()` method of your adapter you would check the position of your `selectItem` and the current item if they were equal then set the background to your view else remove the background from your view.

You can search creating custom adapter for `listView` in the net there are lots of examples.